# Access remote MySQL database from windows 8 app

Tags: mysql, windows-8

I need to access MySQL database which is located in remote server. I need to fetch data and display it in Windows 8 App (HTML/Javascript). Is there any API or JS framework available which can access remote database.

I don't want to store database in windows 8 app, I just need to retrieve it from remote.

Comment: A similar question found answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344903/windows-8-mysql-what-are-my-options).


Regards.

Comment: I have found this question but i need to access it in WIndows 8 app based on "HTML/JAVASCRIPT" only.

Comment: Answer is the same instead of SQLite it's IndexedDB but the best way is creating a front end web service, exposing JSon for example and then consuming it within your app using [WinJS.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) function

Comment: yes.. this seems quite suitable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create web service and consume it in your application.

Comment: please provider more content in your solution

Comment: Yes. thats what im thinking about now. but searched for simple solution without making any service. was searching for prebuild API or services which reduces development time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the previous post is getting downvoted, but here's a deeper explanation:

As per the design models put forward by Microsoft in its examples and the need for highly-responsive applications, The preferred method for getting data into Windows 8 apps is via web services. This allows you to do things like use the async/await keywords so that your application can stay responsive while getting data. There's very little reason to use a database over the web service.

You should check here for a data usage example with the HTML/Javascript app:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974582.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use WCF Service this best way.

Answer (score 0):

I used MySQL connector look this example:

https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net

i have not tested on a remote database so far, but works on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Well I recently did some tweaking with Windows store apps and Php and this is what I've come up with it's not much but it can give you a start up.

You can use MySQL with Php and then echo out the data. This is from where JavaScript / HTML windows store can fetch the data by using JQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET" //POST GET your choice
    url: " " //paste the php script that retrieves the data from the database
    success: function (output){
         $('#myDiv').append(data);
    }
});
```

Please do keep in mind this is just an unauthorized way of accessing data from MySQL through PHP.

The HTML can be for default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- test references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/myScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="myDiv">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```